# Unwanted spaces around characters in regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Consider the following string variable:

```
data = '23jodfjkle lj ioerz\nlkdsjflj sldjj\\difd ioiörjlezr'
```

What i want to create is string with alphabetical characters, character \n and character ö. Therefore i wrote the following:

```
(" ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+|\n|ö", data)))
```

But what i take is:

```
'jodfjkle ljkgfj opz ioerz \n lkdsjflj sldjj difd ioi ö rjlezr'
```

Why are there spaces around the characters \n and ö? What should i change in order to take a solution without spaces:

```
'jodfjkle ljkgfj opz ioerz\nlkdsjflj sldjj difd ioiörjlezr'
```

Comment: You did `" ".join(...)` and are wondering why there are spaces in your output?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm

Comment: Would this regex do what you want? `[a-zA-Zö\n]+`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the `|` operator in your regex, the Python regex parser considers `[a-zA-Z]+`, `\n` and `ö` as different matches. When you use `" ".join()` you therefore introduce a space around all matches, including the `\n` and the `ö`.

To achieve your desired output move the `\n` and `ö` inside the square brackets:

```
print(" ".join(re.findall("[a-zA-Z\nö]+", data)))
```

**Output**

```
jodfjkle lj ioerz\nlkdsjflj sldjj difd ioiörjlezr
```